# Use PowerShell to Query WindowsInstaller.Installer

Tags: powershell, vbscript, windows-installer

I'm trying to build do the PowerShell equivalent of the following VBScript code:

```
' get the version detail
wscript.echo CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer").ProductInfo("{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}", "VersionString")
```

Closest I can come up with is just boolean testing based on ProductCode

```
(New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer).GetType().InvokeMember('Products', [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $(New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer), $null) -contains '{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}'
```

Just looking for a quick way to confirm whether Product X is installed and pull relevant details like version.

Is there an non-complex way of accomplishing the VBScript equivalent in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Translating VBScript code for WindowsInstaller to PowerShell is fairly straightforward, most examples around the web make it unnecessarily complicated.

The VBScript

```
  ' get the version detail
  wscript.echo CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer").ProductInfo("{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}", "VersionString")
```

becomes

```
(New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer).ProductInfo("{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}, "VersionString")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a WMI query against Win32_Product like:

```
gwmi -class Win32_Product -filter 'IdentifyingNumber = "{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}"'
```

Since the IdentifyingNumber should be a unique identifier I would suggest piping it to `|%{$_;break}` so that as soon as it finds a result it stops looking.

```
gwmi -class Win32_Product -filter 'IdentifyingNumber = "{D7A3E989-A6F2-4CD3-A42D-EFC45029C282}"'|%{$_;break}
```

Comment: I agree it is an alternative, as is querying the Uninstaller registry keys, but both are **very** slow whereas the other is under 1 second. Thanks though :)

Comment: Win32_Product has some serious design defects. It's slow and triggers repairs of products that can be seen in event viewer.